# Estudar angular 1 ou 2

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

Sou bem das antigas, a primeira linguagem que aprendi foi em Action Script 1 (isso no começo dos anos 2000). Hoje estou precisando me reciclar e quero começar a abandonar o Jquery e partir para o Angular, principalmente para desenvolver aplicativos com o IONIC 2, pois meu estúdio tem tido muita demanda. Tenho algumas dúvidas:

**1-** Devo já partir para o Angular 2 ou primeiramente entender o Angular 1?

**2-** Mesmo para sites que não sejam SinglePage, Angular é um framework fortemente recomendado, certo?

**3-** Angular é o framework que realmente devo me dedicar, ou vocês entendem ter algum outro que possa se tornar mais usado que ele em  um futuro próximo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Angular JS (Angular 1) é totalmente diferente do 2, ele foi reformulado, então aconselho já partir para o 2.

2 - Eu trabalho direto com o Angular indiferente para o tamanho do projeto, por agilizar muito o desenvolvimento.

3 - Acredito que sim, mas existem outros concorrentes, como o REACT.
Mas angular é mantido pela Google, por isso sempre aconselho seguir nele.

Comment: Obrigado, como trabalho sozinho, ouvir opiniões de terceiros é sempre bom! Da mais confiança para iniciar, pois já tenho visto que terei bastante trabalho para aprender!

Comment: Disponha. Com certeza sempre buscar opiniões é o Ideal.
Realmente pode focar no Angular, Framework muito útil e que tende a crescer cada vez mais.

Comment: Lembrando que o Angular2 está em BETA, ou seja, não é recomendado para produção.

Comment: Se no seu dia a dia vc da suporte a outros sistemas talvez seja melhor entender um pouco de Angular1 no caso de pegar um projeto feito nele, pois acredito que tenha muita coisa rodando com Angular1 e é completamente diferente do 2, a mesma coisa digo do IONIC 2, vale muito a pena aprender, mas no caso de dar uma manutenção em um código antigo vc pode encontrar dificuldades, até a forma como inicia o app ou usa as rotas são muito diferentes, vale a pena ver o básico pelo menos.

Answer (score 1):

Levando em consideração suas questões, sim o angular js é um framework muito ágil pois com ele é possível utilizar módulos e aplicar direto ao seu html, assim torna seu próprio código em um escopo, a facilidade com que ele é aplicável é muito boa.

Passe direto para a última versão por conter novas funcionalidades que facilitam e muito quando comparadas da primeira versão.

E  por fim acredito que deva investir no mesmo, pois tende a crescer ainda mais seu uso e aplicação.